# ContentControl.Content setter always overwrites the content template content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am fighting with this issue for at least a couple of hours already. I tried all possible solution I found on the net. My latest is below and you will see that I am trying to add a simple MenuBar to the main Window control and present the content beneath. My application is using MVVM and the view is assigned like this:
 `myMainWindow.Content = view; // this is what I cannot change`

The soultion should be trivial but none works. I tried with ContentTemplate, ContentPresenter, Style setter, all the variations with binding but nothing works as expected that is whenever myMainWindow.Content menu bar disappears.

None of the samples available on the internet does not actaully show an application with MenuBar and content at the same time.

Is it so hard to add a menu bar in WPF application?
I would be more than happy for any new suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

```
<window:BaseWindow x:Class="OneTwoThree.Manager.MainWindow"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:window="clr-namespace:Xsell.Client.Common;assembly=Xsell.Client.Common"
                   Title="{Binding Title}"
                   Width="1020"
                   Height="750"
                   Closed="AppClosed"
                   Icon="app.ico"
                   Loaded="AppLoaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Grid>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Admin">
                                        <MenuItem Header="Manage Labels"></MenuItem>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </Menu>
                                <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</window:BaseWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application isn't really using MVVM. At best it might be sort of halfway using MVVM.

Meanwhile, all the XAML inside your `<Window>` tag in your main window XAML file is the window's `Content`. And you are explicitly replacing that with some random object, so of course it's not there any more.

You aren't giving much detail, but **you need to assign your main viewmodel to the Window's `DataContext` and not assign anything to the window's `Content`**.

You didn't say what `view` is in this line of code, so I have no idea what you were trying to do there:

```
myMainWindow.Content = view; // this is what I cannot change
```

Is `view` a viewmodel, or a view? Whatever it is, don't do that.

You could assign your main viewmodel to the Window's datacontext in XAML, too:

```
<Window ... >

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<!-- ... -->

</Window>
```

Then bind your viewmodel to the `Content` property of a `ContentPresenter`. There's no need to apply the window's content via a template here so I eliminated that part. The only template you need in this snipppet is the `DataTemplate` which displays your viewmodel in the `ContentPresenter`.

The layout here is copied *verbatim* from `MainWindow.xaml` in a project I recently wrote. I replaced my main menu with yours and omitted my `Window.Resources`. That's the only change.

```
<Window ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="Admin">
                <MenuItem Header="Manage Labels"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter 
                Content="{Binding}"
                />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

A simple `{Binding}` with no `Source` or `Path` etc. properties will bind to the `DataContext`. The `ContentPresenter` will inherit its `DataContext` from the `Window` that contains it.

Then, if you've got a data template defined with a `DataType` the same as your main viewmodel, that data template will be instantiated in that `ContentPresenter`.

"Bind" doesn't mean "assign in code-behind". It means to use the [`System.Windows.Data.Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The easiest way to do that is in the XAML as I've shown above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough explanation. It gave me more understanding about DataContext and binding. 
To give you more data - the current code was launching a Login dialog after which ShowViewContent<IMyCustomView>() was called. This method did the following:
            var view = AppScopeInstance.Resolve<T>(); // T = IMyCustomView            Content = view;

Comment: IGNORE previous - SO editor is quirky.
Thanks a lot for your thorough explanation. It gave me more understanding about DataContext and binding.<br/> 
To give you more data - the current code was launching a Login dialog after which ShowViewContent<IMyCustomView>() was called. This method did the following:
            var view = AppScopeInstance.Resolve<IMyCustomView>(); 
            Content = view; // which was overwriting existing content including MenuBar. <br/>
Changing it to:
           (FindName("contentControl") as ContentControl).Content = view;
helped but it is not ideal.

Comment: @RadekStrugalski You need to use binding like i showed you. Don't try to invent your own way of doing things. Do it the way the framework is meant to be used.

Comment: So the question would be where to put MenuBar? A. In the Window XAML B. In the View XAML. I would incline for A. But then it breaks ShowViewModel<IView>() method which assings view straight to the Content. I was guessing that adding ContentControl in the Window XAML would do the trick but it does not. But your answer encouraged me to look for another reasons why it does not work. I will let you know when I discover anything. Thanks, Radek

Comment: @RadekStrugalski Binding. Binding. Binding. Binding. I told you how to do it. It sounds like you're using some MVVM framework that has its own way of doing things. You should have mentioned that, because if so, this is a question about the framework, not about WPF. Read the framework documentation, or junk the framework and do it right.

Comment: Seems like the original question remains open - I will rephrase it a bit.
How to custruct XAML of the main window so that it contains some common elements like MenuBar but when setting a content from the code behind, no common elements are destroyed/overwritten. Or in other words, like in the ASP masterpage - you have a placeholder for a content and when you set it, no master page is destroyed. I don't care if this is a Content property of the main window or not, but FindName("contentControl") looks a bit hacky for me. Thanks.

Comment: @RadekStrugalski I showed you. It's incredibly simple. It's right there. It's a two minute job. Easiest thing there is. If you don't want to learn XAML, nobody can help you.

Comment: @RadekStrugalski I updated the XAML my answer to clarify exactly how my suggestion applies to your exact case. Good luck.